# How can I solve this implement error? Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am kinda new to programming so sorry if my question is dumb. Also, I'm not a native English speaker so I am sorry if my English is bad. And lastly, this is my first time asking a question here so I would probably make mistakes XD

I am following a tutorial from Youtube on how to make a liquid swipe, but I ran into an error when adding 2 implements:

'com.cuberto:liquid-swipe:1.0.0' , 'com.android.support:design:31.0.0' (originally, it was 29.0.0, but the only way for this to not have errors is by changing it to 31).

the errors say:

> Failed to resolve: com.cuberto:liquid-swipe:1.0.0
> Show in Project Structure dialog
> Affected Modules: app

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:31.0.0
> Show in Project Structure dialog
> Affected Modules: app

What can I do? Thank you!

Comment: for some reason, it deleted like half of the error description when so I'm adding it here. (It is the same for both implements, only with changing the implement: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:31.0.0
<a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/myname/AndroidStudioProjects/appsname/app/build.gradle">app</a>

Answer (score 0):

The library you're trying to included in your app can not be found on the remote server. Check your maven endpoint in your build.gradle file. Also make sure the library (version) you're trying to use is still available.

Comment: thank you!! I will try that (: